# change url of a tab drupal

Tags: uri, routes

I am using private message module.

When i load the private message page  i am getting 3 tabs

```
<pre><li class="active"><a href="/messages">Inbox</a></li>
<li><a href="/messages/sent">Sent messages</a></li>
<li><a href="/messages/new">Write new message</a></li>
</pre>
```

In this i need to change the **inbox url from /messages to /messages/inbox**.

How can i do that ?

Note  : Not using jquery is not the right way i think so for this scenario

Thanks in adavance..

Comment: sounds like you need to change more than just the tab as the class="active" above is suggesting that the inbox itself is located in "/messages" not "/messages/inbox"